# How to create a type from the union of two interfaces?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following:

```
interface Man {
  name: string
}

interface Dog {
  breed: string
}

let manDog: Man | Dog;
```

Is it possible to create a type `ManDog` which is the equivalent of `Man | Dog` so that one could do this:

```
let manDog: ManDog;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `type` keyword (not `let`) to create <strike>a new type</strike> an alias for your union type.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

```
interface Man {
  name: string
}

interface Dog {
  breed: string
}

type ManOrDog = Man | Dog;
```

---

To use effectively these union types, don't forget to have a look on type guards, explained in the same documentation link.

---

**EDIT** : Why did I replaced *new type* by *alias* :

A new type would be another `Interface`, that you could extend and so on.

You cannot create an `Interface` that extends the alias created by `type`.

Also, error messages won't show `ManOrDog`.

In this case, for a **union type**, the alias is the only way.

For an **intersection type** however, you would have the choice between a *new type* with

```
interface ManAndDog extends Man, Dog { }
```

and an *alias*

```
type ManAndDog = Man & Dog;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use inheritance to achieve it

```
 interface ManDog extends Man, Dog {}
```

alternatively as a type like this to have either one of `Man` or `Dog`

```
type ManDog = Man | Dog;
```

Comment: Thanks. Which is considered best practice?

Comment: @camden_kid If you don't plan on adding more functionalities go with option 2)

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `type ManDog = Man | Dog;`?

Comment: inheritance doesn corresponds to a union type, it corresponds more to an intersection type.

Comment: @camden_kid Oh. It depends if you want to have both types together or either one of them. Otherwise it's `|` as you said it.

Comment: I want either one of them. So, for example, I would like to create an array of men and dogs.

Comment: @camden_kid Then it's `type ManDog = Man | Dog;`.

Comment: @MuratK.  this what it means to have the "Union" (In question title) of two type : one *or* the other