# Is there a defined behavior for making a Union type alias between two related interfaces?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I came into an interesting scenario, and I couldn't find any information online or in documentation regarding it.

Consider the following scenario:

```
interface A {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

interface B extends A {
    baz: string;
}

export type C = B | A;
```

So using type `C` as defined above always defaults to type `A` in my environment, even sometimes when the type is forced in other places. I'm wondering if this is some default behavior either by typescript compiler or the IDE that defaults to the base-level interface (`A` in this example)

For example:

```
const fooBar = (props: C) => {
    const {
        foo, // okay
        bar, // okay
        baz // error in IDE, baz not found in 'A'
    } = props // have to force it with "as B";

    return(
        {baz ? baz : ""} // if baz exists, render it
    );
}
```

Comment: Your example is pseudocode or has typos in it; could you make sure that if someone pastes it into their own IDE it is a [mre] of your issue?

Comment: Object types in TS aren't sealed and unions are inclusive, so an `A` might have any type property at all at key `baz` and therefore so could `C`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370791/2887218 .  If you make the union exclusive as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WYLlEm) then your problem goes away.  Does that fully address your question or am I missing something?

Comment: That may be an explanation to the issue, if I can confirm this at a later date, I'll close this question if there are no other answers

Comment: Note that `{baz && baz}` still causes typescript errors unrelated to your question; are you trying to write `{ ...(baz && { baz }) }` or something?  Could you [edit]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a type from the union of two interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882213/how-to-create-a-type-from-the-union-of-two-interfaces)

Comment: The most recent edit is still invalid code for an object literal.  I made a suggestion above for fixing your object should work, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mZBv9m).  You might want to [edit] again to use that.  I'm not sure if there's a communication barrier here, so please let me know if you do or do not understand that `{baz ? baz : ""}` is invalid TS/JS and will not do what you want, and has little to do with the question you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is some interface and `B extends A`, then `B | A` is simply `A`. That is, the union of `A` and `B`, defined to be the smallest type which contains both constituent types, is simply `A`, since every `B` is an `A`.

So when you take an argument of type `B | A`, it actually only has to satisfy `A`. If you want to force a type to satisfy *both* `B` and `A` together, then you meant `B & A`, the *intersection* type. Though, again, since there's a pre-existing subtyping relationship, `B & A` is just `B`.